# UIScrollView Customize size(not getting)

Tags: iphone, uiscrollview, xcode4.5

I'm having an `UIScrollView` attached to a `UIView` using `interfacebuilder`, to that `UIScrollView` I added `subviews`, `UILabels`, `UIButtons` etc.

In my .m file i have given like this

```
[testscroll setScrollEnabled:YES];

[self.testscroll setContentSize:CGSizeMake(320, 1560)];
```

I can visible `UIScrollView` but it is up to the limit(not for the totalview) I increased height in `setContentSize` but there is no use

I think this is the simple question but am not getting it please help me.

Comment: What is your scroll view's frame size? Can you mention it checking in interface builder?

Comment: why u used testscroll and self.testscroll?

Comment: @Rushi (0,44,320,900)

Comment: @Sindu where are you writing [testscroll setScrollEnabled:YES]; [self.testscroll setContentSize:CGSizeMake(320, 1560)]; two lines?

Comment: @Sindu Try to put this code in viewDidAppear and check.

Comment: check you xib you have properly connect IBOutlet of your scrollView and also given delegate of UIscrollview or not.? and yes do not forget to add UIscrollviewDelegate in to .h file

Comment: i have given all those

Answer (score 0):

Check the height of the scroll at IB.
If the view height and scroll content height are same then the scroll would not scroll.
Check the scroll height at IB and reduce accordingly

Answer (score 0):

Check out these scenario this may help,
1>first check you bind scrollview correctly.
2>if you make property of scrollview then only use self. testscroll
3>set the content size in ViewdidLoad